# two dimmer switches in one box operating two ceiling fans and lights...how to wire

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

In my current box I have two single pole switches.  one turns on the lights for two ceiling fans.  the other switch turns on the fans for both ceiling fans.
I want to put dimmers on both fans and lights.
both single pole switches have three wires (no ground) feeding them.
One switch has two red and one white.
The other switch has black and white stripe, black, and white.
How do I make the connections?

Comment: Dimmers can't operate fans.  If you want to have variable speed on a fan, you need a **fan speed control**.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box?

Comment: The right switch, bottom red/white wire is hot.  Could not locate any hot on the left side switch.

Comment: where to send the pic.  need email or phone to text.  do not know how to post a pic on this site.